# url amigable con variables dinamicas

Tags: .htaccess

Mi .htaccess contiene lo siguiente

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errores/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errores/500.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Con esto logro que para que me envie a la siguiente direccion

```
miweb.com/directorio/facturas.php
```

basta con escribir lo siguiente en la barra de direcciones

```
miweb.com/directorio/facturas
```

Pero para ir por ejemplo a:

```
miweb.com/directorio/nuevaorden.php?servicio=449
```

tengo que dirigirme a:

```
miweb.com/directorio/nuevaorden?servicio=449
```

Yo lo que busco es que se muestre algo como:

```
miweb.com/directorio/nuevaorden/449
```

Pero no encuentro como hacerlo, alguna idea?

Comment: intenta con esta `RewriteRule    ^nuevaorden.php/([0-9]+)/?$    nuevaorden.php?servicio=$1    [NC,L]`

Comment: Edite lo que busco que se muestre porque lo escribi mal. De todos modos, con esa regla me da error 500 tanto si pruebo con directorio/449 como si intento con directorio/nuevaorden/449